before_round_data_depolarization in Stim surface code circuits
I am working with Stim to do some circuit-level noise simulations and I have a doubt on the noise model and the stim implementation. I can generate stim circuits for the surface code using the following lines:
circuit = stim.Circuit.generated(
    "surface_code:rotated_memory_x",
    rounds=3,
    distance=3,
    before_round_data_depolarization=p,
    before_measure_flip_probability=p,
    after_reset_flip_probability=p,
    after_clifford_depolarization=p)

My main question relates to the before_round_data_depolarization, which I understand as a depolarizing error introduced before each extraction round. In my mind, this makes sense as in the phenomenological model we do have those while the gates and SPAM are assumed to be noiseless. Circuit-level noise would be the same thing but with noisy gates and SPAM. However, most of papers on circuit-level noise do not discuss this noise source, i.e. before_round_data_depolarization. See  the noise model description in Improved Decoding of Circuit Noise and Fragile Boundaries of Tailored Surface Codes. However, in pymatching and beliefmatching (as well as in stim), the constructions do include such noise model. Since the Stim circuits are similar to the one I previously wrote. The output of such stim coed is the following:
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 1) 1
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 0) 2
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 1) 3
QUBIT_COORDS(5, 1) 5
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 3) 8
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 2) 9
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 3) 10
QUBIT_COORDS(4, 2) 11
QUBIT_COORDS(5, 3) 12
QUBIT_COORDS(6, 2) 13
QUBIT_COORDS(0, 4) 14
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 5) 15
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 4) 16
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 5) 17
QUBIT_COORDS(4, 4) 18
QUBIT_COORDS(5, 5) 19
QUBIT_COORDS(4, 6) 25
RX 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19
Z_ERROR(0.01) 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19
R 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
X_ERROR(0.01) 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
TICK
DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19 (HERE!!!!!!)
H 2 11 16 25
DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 2 11 16 25
TICK
CX 2 3 16 17 11 12 15 14 10 9 19 18
DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 2 3 16 17 11 12 15 14 10 9 19 18
TICK
CX 2 1 16 15 11 10 8 14 3 9 12 18
DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 2 1 16 15 11 10 8 14 3 9 12 18
TICK
CX 16 10 11 5 25 19 8 9 17 18 12 13
DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 16 10 11 5 25 19 8 9 17 18 12 13
TICK
CX 16 8 11 3 25 17 1 9 10 18 5 13
DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 16 8 11 3 25 17 1 9 10 18 5 13
TICK
H 2 11 16 25
DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 2 11 16 25
TICK
X_ERROR(0.01) 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
MR 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
X_ERROR(0.01) 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
DETECTOR(2, 0, 0) rec[-8]
DETECTOR(2, 4, 0) rec[-3]
DETECTOR(4, 2, 0) rec[-6]
DETECTOR(4, 6, 0) rec[-1]
REPEAT 2 {
    TICK
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19 (HERE!!!!!!)
    H 2 11 16 25
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 2 11 16 25
    TICK
    CX 2 3 16 17 11 12 15 14 10 9 19 18
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 2 3 16 17 11 12 15 14 10 9 19 18
    TICK
    CX 2 1 16 15 11 10 8 14 3 9 12 18
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 2 1 16 15 11 10 8 14 3 9 12 18
    TICK
    CX 16 10 11 5 25 19 8 9 17 18 12 13
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 16 10 11 5 25 19 8 9 17 18 12 13
    TICK
    CX 16 8 11 3 25 17 1 9 10 18 5 13
    DEPOLARIZE2(0.01) 16 8 11 3 25 17 1 9 10 18 5 13
    TICK
    H 2 11 16 25
    DEPOLARIZE1(0.01) 2 11 16 25
    TICK
    X_ERROR(0.01) 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
    MR 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
    X_ERROR(0.01) 2 9 11 13 14 16 18 25
    SHIFT_COORDS(0, 0, 1)
    DETECTOR(2, 0, 0) rec[-8] rec[-16]
    DETECTOR(2, 2, 0) rec[-7] rec[-15]
    DETECTOR(4, 2, 0) rec[-6] rec[-14]
    DETECTOR(6, 2, 0) rec[-5] rec[-13]
    DETECTOR(0, 4, 0) rec[-4] rec[-12]
    DETECTOR(2, 4, 0) rec[-3] rec[-11]
    DETECTOR(4, 4, 0) rec[-2] rec[-10]
    DETECTOR(4, 6, 0) rec[-1] rec[-9]
}
Z_ERROR(0.01) 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19
MX 1 3 5 8 10 12 15 17 19
DETECTOR(2, 0, 1) rec[-8] rec[-9] rec[-17]
DETECTOR(2, 4, 1) rec[-2] rec[-3] rec[-5] rec[-6] rec[-12]
DETECTOR(4, 2, 1) rec[-4] rec[-5] rec[-7] rec[-8] rec[-15]
DETECTOR(4, 6, 1) rec[-1] rec[-2] rec[-10]
OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(0) rec[-3] rec[-6] rec[-9]

I can't use bold font in the code, so I added (HERE!!!!!!) to represent where the before_round_data_depolariztion appears in the coed. So as I was mentioning it refers to a depolarizing error in each data qubit before each extraction round. Furthermore, in this question, the mains question asks if the model is CLN. The answer regarding before_round_data_depolarization is that it's there for phenomenological noise model to be easily implemented or to model idling time on measurements (this does make sense in my mind). Thus, I have the following questions:

Do we really don't add the errors to the data qubits before each round in CLN?
If the explanation is that we want to add idling to the measurements (that take more time), then why does the circuit add the depolarization error before the first round? There is no check measurement before the measurement round for the surface code.
For the BB codes constructed in SlidingWindowDecoder, it seems that the before_round_data_depolarization parameter seems to be used to only to model the idle part of the extraction circuit. Seems that there is no true before_round_data_depolarization here. Does this mean that the simulations for surface codes are noisier? Wouldn't that change the overall performance of BB vs surface codes if the same model was used?


Note that these Stim circuit generators have been created as toy examples / for demonstration purposes. It is generally a hard task to implement a simple example which is highly parametrizable which may explain why errors happen at some unexpected spots. Generally, if you want to use Stim to implement your own experiments, it is better to implement your own circuit from scratch, so that you can add noise where your model deems necessary.
